# Cannot deserialize specified PropertyName in Json Result.(Survey Gizmo API)

Tags: json, exception, json.net, deserialization, survey

//Here is a copy of Json Result:

//-----------------------the previous json result ---neglect pls------------
    {
      "result_ok": true,
      "total_count": "4",
      "page": 1,
      "total_pages": 1,
      "results_per_page": 50,
      "data": [
      {
      "id": "1",
      "contact_id": "",
      "status": "Complete",
      "is_test_data": "1",
      "datesubmitted": "2011-12-09 02:07:33",
      "[question(2)]": "Victor",
      "[question(11)]": "",
      "[question(11), question_pipe(\": "",
      "[url(\": "f299f5ef90291d40543fc731bb1fd755",
      "[variable(\": "0",
      "[variable(5)]": "10009"
      }
      ]
    }

//-----------------------the previous json result ---neglect pls------------

Full json context:

```
{"result_ok":true,"total_count":"4","page":1,"total_pages":1,"results_per_page":50,"data":[{"id":"1","contact_id":"","status":"Complete","is_test_data":"1","datesubmitted":"2011-12-09 02:07:33","[question(2)]":"Victor","[question(4), option(10001)]":"Oral Roberts","[question(4), option(10002)]":"","[question(4), option(10003)]":"Kansas St","[question(4), option(10004)]":"","[question(4), option(10005)]":"Notre Dame","[question(4), option(10007)]":"","[question(4), option(10008)]":"","[question(5)]":"Black pattern","[question(6), option(10012)]":"Logo1.gif","[question(6), option(10013)]":"Logo3.jpg","[question(6), option(10014)]":"","[question(6), option(10016)]":"","[question(8), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"Man","[question(8), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"Woman","[question(8), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"Man","[question(9), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"NBA","[question(9), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"WCBA","[question(9), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"NBA","[question(10), option(10024), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"Average Height","[question(10), option(10025), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"Muscle","[question(10), option(10026), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"","[question(10), option(10027), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"","[question(10), option(10025), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"Muscle","[question(10), option(10026), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"","[question(10), option(10024), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"","[question(10), option(10025), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"Muscle","[question(10), option(10027), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"","[question(11)]":"","[question(11), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"","[question(11), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"","[question(11), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"","[question(13)]":"20-99","[question(15)]":"Furniture","[question(16), option(10044)]":"","[question(17)]":"","[question(18), option(10053)]":"","[question(18), option(10054)]":"","[question(18), option(10056)]":"KINWAI","[url(\"id\")]":"746788","[url(\"crc\")]":"f299f5ef90291d40543fc731bb1fd755","[variable(\"STANDARD_IP\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_LONG\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_LAT\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOCOUNTRY\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOCITY\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOREGION\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOPOSTAL\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_RESPONSETIME\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_COMMENTS\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEODMA\")]":"0","[variable(5)]":"10009","[variable(8)]":"","[variable(8), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"10017","[variable(8), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"10018","[variable(8), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"10017","[variable(9)]":"","[variable(9), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"10019","[variable(9), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"10023","[variable(9), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"10019","[variable(13)]":"10031","[variable(15)]":"10042","[variable(17)]":""},{"id":"2","contact_id":"","status":"Partial","is_test_data":"1","datesubmitted":"2011-12-09 02:08:11","[question(2)]":"Jerry","[question(4), option(10001)]":"","[question(4), option(10002)]":"","[question(4), option(10003)]":"","[question(4), option(10004)]":"","[question(4), option(10005)]":"","[question(4), option(10007)]":"Harvard","[question(4), option(10008)]":"","[question(5)]":"Black pattern","[question(6), option(10012)]":"","[question(6), option(10013)]":"Logo3.jpg","[question(6), option(10014)]":"Logo4.jpg","[question(6), option(10016)]":"","[question(8), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"Man","[question(8), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"Woman","[question(8), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"Man","[question(9), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"NBA","[question(9), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"WCBA","[question(9), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"CBA","[question(10), option(10024), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"","[question(10), option(10025), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"","[question(10), option(10026), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"","[question(10), option(10027), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"","[question(10), option(10025), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"","[question(10), option(10026), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"","[question(10), option(10024), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"","[question(10), option(10025), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"","[question(10), option(10027), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"","[question(11)]":"","[question(11), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"","[question(11), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"","[question(11), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"","[question(13)]":"100-499","[question(15)]":"Clothing","[question(16), option(10044)]":"","[question(17)]":"Dark","[question(18), option(10053)]":"","[question(18), option(10054)]":"","[question(18), option(10056)]":"","[url(\"id\")]":"746788","[url(\"crc\")]":"f299f5ef90291d40543fc731bb1fd755","[variable(\"STANDARD_IP\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_LONG\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_LAT\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOCOUNTRY\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOCITY\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOREGION\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOPOSTAL\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_RESPONSETIME\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_COMMENTS\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEODMA\")]":"0","[variable(5)]":"10009","[variable(8)]":"","[variable(8), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"10017","[variable(8), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"10018","[variable(8), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"10017","[variable(9)]":"","[variable(9), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"10019","[variable(9), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"10023","[variable(9), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"10020","[variable(13)]":"10032","[variable(15)]":"10040","[variable(17)]":"10050"},{"id":"3","contact_id":"","status":"Complete","is_test_data":"1","datesubmitted":"2011-12-09 02:19:42","[question(2)]":"todd","[question(4), option(10001)]":"","[question(4), option(10002)]":"","[question(4), option(10003)]":"Kansas St","[question(4), option(10004)]":"West Virginia","[question(4), option(10005)]":"","[question(4), option(10007)]":"","[question(4), option(10008)]":"Connecticut","[question(5)]":"Orange pattern","[question(6), option(10012)]":"Logo1.gif","[question(6), option(10013)]":"Logo3.jpg","[question(6), option(10014)]":"","[question(6), option(10016)]":"Logo2.jpg","[question(8), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"Woman","[question(8), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"Woman","[question(8), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"Woman","[question(9), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"ACB","[question(9), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"EML","[question(9), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"CBA","[question(10), option(10024), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"Average Height","[question(10), option(10025), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"Muscle","[question(10), option(10026), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"Beard","[question(10), option(10027), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"WaveHairs","[question(10), option(10025), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"Muscle","[question(10), option(10026), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"Beard","[question(10), option(10024), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"Average Height","[question(10), option(10025), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"","[question(10), option(10027), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"WaveHairs","[question(11)]":"","[question(11), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"ddd","[question(11), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"dd","[question(11), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"ddd","[question(13)]":"10-19","[question(15)]":"Furniture","[question(16), option(10044)]":"","[question(17)]":"","[question(18), option(10053)]":"QUANU","[question(18), option(10054)]":"HUARI","[question(18), option(10056)]":"","[url(\"id\")]":"746788","[url(\"crc\")]":"f299f5ef90291d40543fc731bb1fd755","[variable(\"STANDARD_IP\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_LONG\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_LAT\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOCOUNTRY\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOCITY\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOREGION\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOPOSTAL\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_RESPONSETIME\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_COMMENTS\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEODMA\")]":"0","[variable(5)]":"10010","[variable(8)]":"","[variable(8), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"10018","[variable(8), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"10018","[variable(8), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"10018","[variable(9)]":"","[variable(9), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"10021","[variable(9), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"10022","[variable(9), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"10020","[variable(13)]":"10030","[variable(15)]":"10042","[variable(17)]":""},{"id":"4","contact_id":"","status":"Partial","is_test_data":"1","datesubmitted":"2011-12-09 02:21:10","[question(2)]":"suan","[question(4), option(10001)]":"Oral Roberts","[question(4), option(10002)]":"Oklahoma","[question(4), option(10003)]":"","[question(4), option(10004)]":"","[question(4), option(10005)]":"","[question(4), option(10007)]":"","[question(4), option(10008)]":"","[question(5)]":"Red pattern","[question(6), option(10012)]":"Logo1.gif","[question(6), option(10013)]":"","[question(6), option(10014)]":"","[question(6), option(10016)]":"","[question(8), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"Man","[question(8), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"Man","[question(8), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"Man","[question(9), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"NBA","[question(9), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"NBA","[question(9), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"NBA","[question(10), option(10024), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"","[question(10), option(10025), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"Muscle","[question(10), option(10026), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"","[question(10), option(10027), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"WaveHairs","[question(10), option(10025), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"Muscle","[question(10), option(10026), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"","[question(10), option(10024), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"","[question(10), option(10025), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"Muscle","[question(10), option(10027), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"","[question(11)]":"","[question(11), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"","[question(11), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"","[question(11), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"china","[question(13)]":"20-99","[question(15)]":"House-hold","[question(16), option(10044)]":"TV","[question(17)]":"","[question(18), option(10053)]":"","[question(18), option(10054)]":"","[question(18), option(10056)]":"","[url(\"id\")]":"746788","[url(\"crc\")]":"f299f5ef90291d40543fc731bb1fd755","[variable(\"STANDARD_IP\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_LONG\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_LAT\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOCOUNTRY\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOCITY\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOREGION\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOPOSTAL\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_RESPONSETIME\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_COMMENTS\")]":"","[variable(\"STANDARD_GEODMA\")]":"0","[variable(5)]":"10011","[variable(8)]":"","[variable(8), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"10017","[variable(8), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"10017","[variable(8), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"10017","[variable(9)]":"","[variable(9), question_pipe(\"Kobe Bryant\")]":"10019","[variable(9), question_pipe(\"Miao li Jie\")]":"10019","[variable(9), question_pipe(\"Yao Min\")]":"10019","[variable(13)]":"10031","[variable(15)]":"10039","[variable(17)]":""}]}
```

I have tried entity class  :

//Entity Class

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
[JsonConverter(typeof(SurveryResponseConverter))]
public class SurveyResponse
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Reponse ID
    /// </summary>
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, PropertyName = "id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contact id
    /// </summary>
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, PropertyName = "contact_id")]
    public string contact_id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reponse status
    /// </summary>
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, PropertyName = "status")]
    public string status { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Is test data?
    /// </summary>
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, PropertyName = "is_test_data")]
    public bool is_test_data { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// when submitt the response?
    /// </summary>
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, PropertyName = "date_submitted")]
    public string date_submitted { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Dictionary<string, Question> Questions { get; set; }
}


[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Option
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Dictionary<string, QuestionPipe> Options { get; set; }
}



[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Question
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore )]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore )]
    public Dictionary<string, Option> Options { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Dictionary<string, QuestionPipe> QuestionPipes { get; set; }
}



[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class QuestionPipe
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

//Converter Class

```
public class SurveryResponseConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(SurveyResponse);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader jsonReader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = (SurveyResponse)existingValue;
        if (value == null)
        {
            value = new SurveyResponse();
            value.Questions = new Dictionary<string, Question>();
        }

        //string readResult = "{\n";
        while (jsonReader.Read())
        {
            if (jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
            {
                var name = jsonReader.Value.ToString();

                if (name.StartsWith("[question("))
                {
                    jsonReader.Read();//read the value

                    Regex regexQuestion = null ;//omitted for saving context
                    Regex regexQuestionAndOption = null;//omitted for saving context
                    Regex regexQuestionAndQuestionPipe =  null;//omitted for saving context
                    Regex regexQuestionAndOptionAndQuestionPipe =null;//omitted for saving context

                    bool isMatchQuestion, isMatchQuestionAndOption, isMatchQuestionAndPipe, isMatchQuestionAndOptionAndPipe;
                    isMatchQuestion = regexQuestion.IsMatch(name);
                    isMatchQuestionAndOption = regexQuestionAndOption.IsMatch(name);
                    isMatchQuestionAndPipe = regexQuestionAndQuestionPipe.IsMatch(name);
                    isMatchQuestionAndOptionAndPipe = regexQuestionAndOptionAndQuestionPipe.IsMatch(name);

                    //bool isMatchQuestionAndOption, isMatchQuestionAndPipe, isMatchQuestionAndOptionAndPipe;
                    if (isMatchQuestion)
                    {
                        //eg.[question(int)]
                        int index = int.Parse(name.Substring(10, name.IndexOf(')') - 10));
                        string strValue = serializer.Deserialize<string>(jsonReader);
                        Question questionValue = new Question();
                        questionValue.Key = index.ToString();
                        questionValue.Value = strValue;
                        value.Questions[index.ToString()] = questionValue;
                    }
                    else if (isMatchQuestionAndOption)
                    {
                        //eg.[question(4), option(10001)]
                        string questionKey =  name.Substring(10, name.IndexOf(')') - 10);
                        string questionOptionValue = serializer.Deserialize<string>(jsonReader);
                        string questionOptionKey = name.Substring(name.LastIndexOf('(')+1, name.LastIndexOf(')') - name.LastIndexOf('(')-1);

                        Option optionValue = new Option();
                        optionValue.Key = questionOptionKey;
                        optionValue.Value = serializer.Deserialize<string>(jsonReader);
                    }
                    else if (isMatchQuestionAndPipe)
                    {
                        //eg.[question(10),question_pipe(" some description of question")]
                        string questionKey = name.Substring(10, name.IndexOf(')') - 10);
                        QuestionPipe questionPipe = new QuestionPipe();
                        questionPipe.Key = "TODO";
                        questionPipe.Value = name.Substring(name.LastIndexOf('(') + 1, name.LastIndexOf(')') - name.LastIndexOf('(') - 1);
                        questionPipe.Answer = serializer.Deserialize<string>(jsonReader);

                    }
                    else if (isMatchQuestionAndOptionAndPipe)
                    {
                        //eg.[question(10), option(10024), question_pipe(" some description of question")]
                        string questionKey = name.Substring(10, name.IndexOf(')') - 10);

                        string subName = name.Substring(name.IndexOf('('));
                        Option optionValue = new Option();
                        optionValue.Key = subName.Substring(1, subName.IndexOf(')') - 1);

                        QuestionPipe questionPipe = new QuestionPipe();
                        questionPipe.Key = "TODO";
                        questionPipe.Value = name.Substring(name.LastIndexOf('(') + 1, name.LastIndexOf(')') - name.LastIndexOf('(') - 1);
                        questionPipe.Answer = serializer.Deserialize<string>(jsonReader);
                    }
                }
                else if (name.StartsWith("[variable("))
                {
                    //TODO
                }
                else if (name.StartsWith("[url("))
                {
                    //TODO
                }
                else
                {
                    var property = typeof(SurveyResponse).GetProperty(name);
                    try
                    {
```

**//Here will be a exception : Unexpected token while deserializing object: PropertyName**
                            var propertyValue = serializer.Deserialize(jsonReader, property.PropertyType);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            string errMsg = ex.Message;
                            throw;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

```
        return value;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Would you like give me some advice?Merry Christmas every body ^_^

Answer (score 0):

JSON is invalid, things start getting crazy around question_pipe.  Here is a link to an online validator to help you clean it up.  http://jsonlint.com/

Hopefully in your case, you have some control over how the object is serialized otherwise you may have to clean up/escape the illegal characters in the string before you attempt to deserialize.  Hope this helps, happy holidays!

**Update**

After reading your full JSON example, I'm curious to see how your objects are getting serialized.  Do you have a custom serializer to get this JSON?  The reason why, is JSON is just a very simple object notation.  You'll find that a lot of times, JSON is deserialized to a Dictionary meaning it's a simple key value pair.  The JSON you have listed is far more complex than that and I wonder if that is not your problem.

For example... lets just look at a simple object:

```
public class Person
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person Sibling { get; set; }

}
```

A valid JSON representation of that would be:

```
{ 
    "FirstName": "John", 
    "LastName": "Doe", 
    "Sibling": 
    {
        "FirstName": "Jane", 
        "LastName": "Doe", 
        "Sibling": null
    }
}
```

Very simple, representation.  You have a string for each property name and then the corresponding value.  In your case, you have property names like **[question(4), option(10001)]** and I'm not sure any standard serializer would know how to handle that.  It's just looking for a one to one match and there's no way to create a property name **[question(4), option(10001)]** by itself.  There are definitely invalid characters in there, so what would the real property name be?

I think there are some definite design considerations here.  I hope this helps explain why the parser is throwing errors.  Maybe I don't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish but I hope my explanation helps shed some light on potential issues and conceptual design considerations.

Happy Holidays!

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I'm sorry that I modified the json manually for saving the context of question, now the whole json result is ok after verified,would you like viewing the new json content?

Comment: Full json result context was provided, would you like do me a favor?

Comment: So are you getting this JSON by using a JSON serializer to convert that SurveyResponse object, or basically object graph?  I still have some questions as to why there are brackets in what would be deserialized as a Property name... which sounds like the exception you are getting.  Now, I am viewing this on my iPad so maybe I'm missing something